# How to understand the code for matplotlib.pyplot.contour?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have found that the function I am writing works similarly (but not identically) to the contour function in matplotlib.pyplot. I'm trying to read the the python to understand how it works in detail.

Can someone point me to the place in the code where it finds the first point at a given level and starts "following" it around? Also, where it decides if it has found a second, distinct place where it is following a different set of points which also have the same level?

For example, some of these contours show places where tan wraps from positive to negative infinity. I'd like to avoid these 'zeros'. Take a look at these plots:

```
def nanifbig(f, lo, hi):
    g = f.copy()
    g[g<lo] = np.nan
    g[g>hi] = np.nan
    return g

import numpy              as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

zero = np.array([0.0])

x = np.linspace(0, 8, 401)
y = np.linspace(0, 4, 201)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

extent = [x[0], x[-1], y[0], y[-1]]

F = np.tan(X + 0.02*Y**2)

lo, hi = -2, 2
Fc = F.clip(lo, hi)
Fnanifbig = nanifbig(F, lo, hi)

Fnan = F.copy()
Fnan[:] = np.nan

plt.figure()

plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.imshow(Fc, origin='lower', extent=extent)
plt.contour(Fc, zero, linewidths=2, extent=extent)

plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.imshow(Fnanifbig, origin='lower', extent=extent)
plt.contour(Fc, zero, linewidths=2, extent=extent)

plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.imshow(Fnan, origin='lower', extent=extent)
plt.contour(Fc, zero, linewidths=2, extent=extent)

plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.plot(x, F[0,:])

plt.show()
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: For performance reasons, the point that "follows" a given level around is in C: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/src/cntr.c  Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to do?  At first glance, it seems like you might want to mask a portion of your input...

Comment: @Joe The code I included helps illustrate what I'm after. I'm writing my own "finder" for tracing the paths of zeros of multi-dimensional functions (partly just to get better at python) using spo.brentq and spo.root. Sometimes I use contour to to help visualize in 2D slices, which piqued my interest in how contour works. So I'm hoping that someone familiar would help me find my way through that function. Your link is VERY helpful! I would call it an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Joe Kington supplied a comment containing the answer. The code  requested is in C and can be found at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/src/cntr.c